# Mocking schema registry service from Kafka for Junits

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

In my project ,we have tooling to provide IaaS. As part of this, we do schema compatibility check for while creating or updating the kafka topics. For Junits, we have mocked the schema registry (SR) implementation where we have coded per our need. However with evolving scenario, it is difficult and error prone to make the mock implementation in sync with actual schema registry work. Is there a better way to handle the mocks for SR?

Answer (score 1):

The Schema Registry project already includes a `MockSchemaRegistryClient` class, but rather than "sync" anything, make a copy of the schema before you update it, and move it to your test resources, then loop over all schema files for compatibility checks

For integration testing, you could use Testcontainers

Comment: thanks let me check the details further